laminas-soap laravel como agregar complexType strategy
no tengo mucho entendimiento de laminas-soap, estoy intentando utilizar un complextype como respuesta pero me da el siente error:

Cannot add a complex type app\Classes\voucherGetOut that is not an
object or where class could not be found in "DefaultComplexType"
strategy.

controlador:
public function wsdlAction(Request $request)
{
    $wsdl = new AutoDiscover();
    $wsdl->setClass(ResponseController::class)
        ->setUri(route('soap-server'))
        ->setServiceName('MySoapService');

    $wsdl = $wsdl->generate();
    $strategy = new ArrayOfTypeComplex();
    $wsdl->setComplexTypeStrategy($strategy);
    $wsdl->addComplexType(voucherGetOut::class);
    return response()->make($wsdl->toXml())
        ->header('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
}

public function serverAction(Request $request)
{
    $server = new Server(
        route('soap-wsdl'), ['actor' => route('soap-server')]
    );
    $server->setClass(ResponseController::class);
    $server->setReturnResponse(true);
    $response = response($server->handle());
    $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

    return $response;
}

Clase ResponseController, tienes las funciones a ejecutar
/**
 *descripcion
 *
 * @param string $magus_id
 * @return app\Classes\voucherGetOut
 */
public function voucherGet($magus_id)
{

    return [
    ];
}

Alguien me puede apoyar por favor, agradezco de antemano la ayuda prestada.

Probaste pasando una instancia (un objeto) en vez de nombre de la clase?
